# Multiplicative inverse in $GF(8)$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, inverse

I've the following problem:

$GF(8)$ is the Galois Field defined by $G(x) = x^3+x+1$. 
$a(x) \in GF(8)$ is $a(x) = x+1$. What is the multiplicative inverse of $a(x)$?

I think it should be applied the Extended Euclidian Algorithm but I do not how to do it since the grade of $a(x)$ is lower the the $G(x)$ one.

Thank you all and sorry for the trivial question!

Comment: There are only eight elements to try, could just try each.

Comment: Surely but I want to know if there another method as well as the "brute-force"

Comment: I can tell by inspection that $x(x+1)^2=x(x^2+1)=x^3+x=1$

Comment: $x^3+x+1=(x^2-x)(x+1)+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using brute force one can try the following:
$GF(8)\simeq \Bbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$.
We use euclidean extended algorithm. Since $\operatorname{gcd}(x^3+x+1,x+1)=1$, we shall find such $a(x),b(x)$ for which $a(x)(x^3+x+1)+b(x)(x+1)=1$, meaning $b(x)(x+1)=1$ in $GF(8)$ (where all calculations are done in $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$).

So, $x^3+x+1=(x^2+x)(x+1)+1$ and therefore $x^3+x+1-(x^2+x)(x+1)=1$.
$-(x^2+x)=x^2+x$ (in $F_2[x]$) so our inverse is $x^2+x$.

Comment: Thank you very useful!